# Error in Listner of RecyclerView on Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have 3 Fragment in my app that contains RecyclerView.

and when I click on first option result is crash!

[this is error of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCg6w.jpg)

Comment: you should to add your code to your main question.
I think you don't initialize the holder of the recycleview holder of your layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log shows you have `NPE` at 72 row. In the row the only cause of NPE is your call `G.context`. Your context is null.

You can obtain valid context by call `view.getContext()` That's it.